# How to create seo friendly urls with php and htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo, friendly-url

I'm trying to generate seo friendly urls using a htaccess file and PHP. But it's not working.

I tried the code below in localhost (running XAMPP)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /real/

RewriteRule ^property-details/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) property-details.php?pid=$1 [NC, L]
```

Comment: It's useful to explain exactly what is "not working" when asking a question. "Not working" is not particularly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways of achieving the same results, but this will give you a guide.

First activate mod_rewrite uncommenting this line in you httpd.conf or apache2.conf file:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
```

Change AllowOverride from none to All to your www directory

```
    <Directory />
        AllowOverride All 
        Require all denied
    </Directory>
```

Restart apache:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

or

```
    sudo service apache2 restart
```

In your www folder, create an .htaccess file and add this:

```
    # | SEO URL                                                                                
    Options +FollowSymLinks  
    RewriteEngine On  
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  
    RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

Then in your index.php file:

```
<?php
    $url_params=get_url_params();

    // then access your url_params
    if (isset($url_params[1]))
    {
        switch ($url_params[1]) 
        {
            case 'login':
                    echo "<h1>Login</h2>";
                break;

            case 'contact':
                    echo "<h1>Cantact</h2>";
                break;

            default:
                echo "<h1>Home</h2>";
                break;
        }

    }

    function get_url_params($site_url='')
    {
        $base_url=explode("/", $site_url);
        $request  = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $url_params = explode("/", $request);
        $delete_extensions=array('.html','.htm');
        $data[]=array();
        foreach ($base_url as $b)
        {
            unset( $url_params[array_search( "$b", $url_params )] );
        }
        foreach ($url_params as $u)
        {
            foreach ($delete_extensions as $e){
                $u=str_replace($e, "", $u);
            }
            $data[]=$u;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> `[NC, L]`

You need to remove the space between your `RewriteRule` flags. This will result in a 500 Internal Server error - in which case you should examine your error logs for a more meaningful error. It should be written as:

```
[NC,L]
```

No spaces.

---

**UPDATE:**
For mod_rewrite to work in per-directory .htaccess files, `FollowSymLinks` must also be enabled (if its not already). At the very top of your .htaccess file, include:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

Comment: tanq w3d. but still the url is not changing. actually i am trying in xampp(localhost) so is there any problem..?

Comment: Initially i get 500 internal server error, now that error not coming after edited the code as u mentioned but the desired url is not coming.(actually no change in my original url)

Comment: Please state in your question the exact URL you are requesting and the desired outcome.

Comment: my actual url is "property-details.php?pid=PID1" and the desired url is "property-details.php/PID1"

Comment: I assume you mean `property-details/PID1` ie. no `.php` in the desired URL? And the code in your question suggests your _actual URL_ is `/real/property-details.php?pid=PID1` - in a `/real` subdirectory - is that not the case? I've updated my answer.

Comment: yes your are correct my desired url is property-details/PID1 . "real" is my project name in htdocs. My project path is xampp->htdocs->real->(here php pages). ".htaccess file is along with my php pages".

Comment: here is my updated code                                                              Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /reall/

RewriteRule ^property-details/([a-zA-Z0-9]+) property-details.php?pid=$1 [NC,L]  still not working

Comment: Your code looks correct, however, the .htaccess file should be located in your document root, not in the subdirectory.

Comment: you mean the .htaccess file path xampp->htdocs-> (here) ? i tried this also with the same above code but still desired url not came.